# Are countries in violation of the ICJ ruling by "squeezing... aid" to UNRWA?

Tags: human-rights, international-court-of-justice

According to this [Channel 4 report on Youtube (starting at around 1:30)](https://youtu.be/tqG2yeF_4sg?t=112), the former UNRWA spokesperson says:

> it's a violation of the ruling by the ICJ which says nobody should squeeze international humanitarian aid - what's Britain and others done? They squeeze the aid

Is there an ICJ ruling (either the one from late January 2024, or another) that is being violated by the countries that have reduced/suspended support for UNRWA?

Comment: Are you arguing that there is a duty to donate aid? If so, how would it be distributed? Should those who haven't given until now step in, or are those who gave once required to give more forever?

Comment: @o.m. No clue. I was surprised to hear this from the spokesperson, hence the question. But it may be possible that drying up the funding of one of the main organisations distributing aid and providing employment is equivalent to withholding aid, due to the result - it may be that no other org can fill the gap left by UNRWA in time to avoid additional mass suffering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ICJ's 24 January 2024 order](https://www.icj-cij.org/index.php/node/203447) was made before Israel's allegations against several UNRWA staff were made public on 25/26 January 2024 (I do not know if the allegations were privately made beforehand).

The [ICJ's 24 January 2024 order](https://www.icj-cij.org/index.php/node/203447) does not mention the United Kingdom; it does not mention UNRWA in this context (it mentions UNRWA in the context of witness statements about the situation in Gaza).

Among other things, the order does say of Israel that:

> 5. The State of Israel shall, pursuant to point (4) (c) above, in relation to Palestinians, desist from, and take all measures within its power including the rescinding of relevant orders, of restrictions and/or of prohibitions to prevent:
>    (a) the expulsion and forced displacement from their homes;
>    (b) the deprivation of:
>    (i) access to adequate food and water;
>    (ii) access to humanitarian assistance, including access to adequate fuel, shelter, clothes, hygiene and sanitation;
>    (iii) medical supplies and assistance; and
>    (c) the destruction of Palestinian life in Gaza.

However, it does not specify that the humanitarian assistance must be done via UNRWA.

---

<sup>[For context](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/cbp-9900/), the UK, European Union, the USA, Canada, Australia, Finland, Germany, the Netherlands and Switzerland "suspended aid to UNRWA in response to reports [by Israel] that “several” UNRWA staff were involved in the 7 October Hamas assault against Israel". UNRWA is not the only mechanism of support, although "In every year from 2014 to 2022, at least half of UK aid to the West Bank and Gaza Strip has been delivered through the UNRWA, rather than through local authorities or civil society groups". Other countries, including Ireland and Norway, said they would not suspend their funding.</sup>

Comment: Is there any other organisation that can immediately take over to ensure there is no loss of aid practically speaking? Because if the answer is no, then this changes the answer.

Comment: @AhmedTawfik The UN's position is that "2 million civilians in Gaza depend on critical aid from UNRWA for daily survival but UNRWA’s current funding will not allow it to meet all requirements to support them in February." Nevertheless, the ICJ order does not oblige the UK to fund UNWRA; it orders Israel to do / not do things, it does not order any other country.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.